# Java combination of bank notes

Tags: java

I am doing a cash dispensing application using Java. The user can add or withdraw money from the ATM, this ATM only supports $50 and $20, it has the initial amount of money of $500, which has 6 * $50 and 10 * $20.

I am able to do either (an amount can be divided by 50, and then the rest amount be divided by 20), or (an amount can be divided by 50), or (an amount can be divided by 20). But I cannot do a combination of bank notes to match a particular amount, like 1 * 50 + 3 * 20 = 110

And to check whether the current number of notes is enough to do a withdrawal request.

I am a beginner in Java, please give me some hits on how to solve it.

```
            if (removeNotes > currentAmount) {
                System.out.println("The ATM don't have enough money to proceed the request");
                continue;
            }

            if ((removeNotes % 50) % 20 == 0 || removeNotes % 50 == 0 || removeNotes % 20 == 0) {
                System.out.println("You have removed " + removeNotes + " dollars");
                currentAmount = currentAmount - removeNotes;
                System.out.println("Current amount: " + currentAmount);
                
                if (currentAmount < 100) {
                    System.out.println("The money in the ATM is running low, please add some money.");
                }
            }

                if ((removeNotes % 50) % 20 == 0) {
                count50 = removeNotes / 50;
                removeNotes = removeNotes % 50;

                count20 = removeNotes / 20;
                removeNotes = removeNotes % 20;

                System.out.println("Remove number of $50 notes: " + count50);
                System.out.println("Remove number of $20 notes: " + count20);
                fiftyDollarNotes = fiftyDollarNotes - count50;
                System.out.println("Total number of $50 notes: " + fiftyDollarNotes);
                twentyDollarNotes = twentyDollarNotes - count20;
                System.out.println("Total number of $20 notes: " + twentyDollarNotes);


            } else if (removeNotes % 50 == 0) {
                count50 = removeNotes / 50;
                System.out.println("Remove number of $50 notes: " + count50);
                fiftyDollarNotes = fiftyDollarNotes - count50;
                System.out.println("Total number of $50 notes: " + fiftyDollarNotes);
                twentyDollarNotes = twentyDollarNotes - count20;
                System.out.println("Total number of $20 notes: " + twentyDollarNotes);

            } else if (removeNotes % 20 == 0) {
                count20 = removeNotes / 20;
                System.out.println("Remove number of $20 notes: " + count20);
                fiftyDollarNotes = fiftyDollarNotes - count50;
                System.out.println("Total number of $50 notes: " + fiftyDollarNotes);
                twentyDollarNotes = twentyDollarNotes - count20;
                System.out.println("Total number of $20 notes: " + twentyDollarNotes);

            } else {
                System.out.println("This ATM only support $20 or $ 50 notes.");
                continue;
            }
```

Comment: What problem are you having with your code? Can you specify?

Comment: When you say "I cannot do a combination of bank notes to match a particular amount" do you mean the problem statement does not permit using a combination of bank notes, or that you can't figure out how to? If the latter, your problem isn't a Java problem, but a math problem. How would you figure out what combination of bills to give if you weren't using a computer?

Comment: how is it supposed to behave? If it is divisible by 50, but not enough 50 notes, does it fall back onto 20 dollar notes?

Comment: Hint: if the amount would require an odd number of tens (e.g., $110 is eleven tens), the bills ***must*** include an odd number of fifties. Otherwise, the remainder could never be made up of any number of twenties.

Comment: @TanYuHauSean, what my code does is, if the number is 170, it is first divided by 50 and then 20, it will give a result of 3*50 and 1*20. If the number is 150, it will be divided by 50, and give a result of 3*50. If the number is 180, it will be divided by 20, and give a result of 9*20. But there is a bug that, if the number is 110, it is first divided by 50 and then 20, so 2*50 and the leftover 10, it will become an invalid withdrawal request, but 110 should be a valid request if I do 1*50 and 3*20, I cannot get this part works.

Comment: @DavidConrad, the problem with my code is, that if a number is greater than 50, it will keep dividing until it is less than 50, then it will try dividing by 20 with the leftover amount, but if the number of 50 and 20 dollars notes are combined correctly, the code should deem that as a valid request.

Comment: @YLChan Then your code is wrong. You should fix it. Again, how would you solve the problem by hand?